# Writing a Web Application in Haxe without Apache and PHP?

Tags: haxe

[Haxe](http://haxe.org/) has Apache httpd modules and can compile to PHP code. These are 2 options I know to make a web application that runs on the server. You can start a http server with nekotools, but this is supposed to be used for development only.

**Are there any more options?**

I can always use the NekoVM from within a C or C++ program, running a web server or interfacing to FastCGI. Or compile to C++, using a FastCGI or web server library. But I want to hear about solutions that are actually used.

I have a VPS with nginx, so no mod_neko or mod_tora. PHP isn't a problem, but I'd rather wouldn't use it (for irrational reasons).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm continuing to keep hxNode up to date and expanding it with the node.js spec.
I'm using it for my own projects and debugging it as I come across stuff.

Currently, hxNode, has the node.js api defined in Haxe, this is the standard node.js asynchronous API. Also, I've started to recreate the Haxe standard API using this API, so for example, `js.FileSystem` has been implemented, this makes use of the fact that latest versions of node can call fs module syncronously.

Other things which I'm working on with this API, servlet's sitting on top, and mongo bindings based on chriskv's mongo native drivers.

bd

Answer (score 4):

More correctly there is an Apache module for the nekoVM. (You do need necessarily haxe to produce neko binaries)

To your question:

- As far as I know there is currently no possibility to use the C++ target for webserver application, but some people are playing arround with some stuff.
- As you said, you could use PHP
- mod_tora or mod_neko on a Apache setup. (Why not use Apache?)
- OR: the probably most interessting thing for you be: [Link 1](http://gamehaxe.com/2009/12/03/neko-on-shared-hosting/) and [Link 2](http://gamehaxe.com/2009/12/04/fastcgi-for-neko-on-share-hosting/) (neko as cgi / fastcgi)

Comment: mod_neko with Apache is the standard thing to do. If you have to use nginx on port 80, you can run Apache on another port, and use nginx as a proxy.

Answer (score 3):

[hxNode](http://github.com/blackdog66/hxNode) uses node.js. Don't know if anybody uses hxNode, but node.js got some good press lately.

Comment: thats true, I forgot about this.

Comment: It's also possible to generate node.js modules using Haxe - see here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14116253/import-haxe-modules-into-a-node-js-script