# Import Haxe modules into a node.js script

Tags: node.js, haxe

Using node.js and Haxe, is there any way to write a function that generates a node.js modules from a Haxe file, and then returns the generated module? I'm started writing node.js modules using Haxe, and I need a way to import the modules more easily.

```
function requireHaxe(variableToRequire, haxeFileLocation){
    //generate a JavaScript module from the Haxe file, and then return the generated JavaScript module
}
```

Comment: This problem shouldn't be too difficult to solve - I just need to find a way to run the Haxe compiler from node.js, get the name of the generated JavaScript file, and then import the generated JavaScript file.

Comment: It's possible to generate node.js modules using Haxe, as described here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/haxelang/6lzIeg6RUC4

Comment: In node.js, it's also possible to execute a system command synchronously. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4443597/node-js-execute-system-command-synchronously

Comment: ...and here's the .hxml file that I'll need to compile haxe to node.js. https://github.com/fukaoi/HaxeNode/blob/master/compile.hxml

Answer (score 6):

Consider this

```
//Haxenode.hx

class Haxenode {
  @:expose("hello")
  public static function hello(){
    return "hello";
  }
}
```

`@:expose("hello")` part is to put something in `module.exports`.

Now launch

```
haxe -js haxenode.js -dce no Haxenode
```

Now you can use `haxenode.js` in nodejs

```
var haxenode = require('./haxenode.js');
var hello = haxenode.hello;
```

So, this combined together is an answer to your question:

```
var cp = require('child_process');

function requireHaxe(haxeClassPath,cb){
    //generate a JavaScript module from the Haxe file, and then return the generated JavaScript module

    cp.exec('haxe -js haxenode.js -dce no ' + haxeClassPath,function(err){
        if (err){
            cb(err); return;
        }

        cb(null,require('./haxenode.js'));
    });
}
```

Mind that output filename is a stub.

But don't do that - better to compile haxe as build step (with all necessary compile options) and then use regular `require` at runtime.